# Repeat each data for a number of times as indicated by itself in a list for python

Tags: python, list

Given a list of integers from 1~9, write code to create a series of new lists, such that each new list will include one digit from the original list, repeated for a number of times as indicated by the number itself. For example, assuming a list as following: `[9, 6, 4, 7, 8, 2, 5]`, the output lists will look as the following:

Part a) Expected output:

```
999999999
666666
4444
7777777
88888888
22
55555
```

It is required that when the data inside `ls` changes and it can still work in valid range and format.
(`rep()` function and panda cannot be used in this question)

Comment: This is homework.  It is unethical to ask us to do your homework.  Show us what you have done, and what results you got.  This is not a hard problem.

Comment: If you haven't already, please help yourselves by taking the [Intro Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Try reading [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also go through [Minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to post your code so that you can get answers in an efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic:

```
l=[9, 6, 4, 7, 8, 2, 5]
for i in l:
    for j in range(i):
        print(i,end="")
    print()
```

Comment: you could just convert to `str` and use `*` as: `[int(str(i)*i) for i in lst]`

Comment: This could be also a simpler form

Answer (score 0):

This way you can solve your problem!

```
for i in [9, 6, 4, 7, 8, 2, 5]:
    print([i for _ in range(i)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = [int(str(num) * num) for num in [9, 6, 4, 7, 8, 2, 5]]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[999999999, 666666, 4444, 7777777, 88888888, 22, 55555]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Method one using normal if loop

```
for i in lst:
    new_lst.append(int(str(i) * i))
print(new_lst)
```

### Method 2 :list comprehensive

```
new_lst = [int(str(i)*i) for i in lst]
print(new_lst)
```

### Method 3 using Lambda and map

```
final_list = list(map(lambda x: int(str(x)*x), lst))
print(final_list)
```